# I got an error in my Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I made a click event by accident, so I removed the code from the clickevent.
But then when I try to run my application, I get the following error.

What am I doing wrong?

> `WindowsFormsTutorial18.Form1` does not contain a definition for
>   `button1_Click` and no extension method `button1_Click` accepting a
>   first argument of type `WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1` could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to look in your designer file. There is a line of code which causes the click event to look for a method.

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the event handler for button1_Click in your code behind file and in the events of the button1 too.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this Line from Designer File:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on your Form name in the Solutions Explorer window and open its Designer mode, which in your case would be ***WindowsFormsTutorial18.Form1.designer.cs***
Search for 'button1_Click' Event handler (like this)

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

and remove it from there.

Comment: @Oellemans Please vote up and accept the answer if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Double click on your error message and it will lead you straight to your underlined part of the code inside your form designer. Delete that part of the code and rerun your application.

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two solutions. One is to select button in design mode and change or delete action in property window. (top part of image) or to edit manually designer file. (bottom part of image) Any changes to this file must be done carefuly![image]